# Executing batch file on Windows 2008 server from CentOS Jenkins instance

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cygwin, windows-server-2008

I have a Jenkins instance running on CentOS and would like the ability to connect to a Windows 2008 virtual server and have execute and write permissions.

Some threads have suggesting CYGWIN, installing on the windows machine and then using SSH to connect. There are also suggestions of telnet and RDP. I wanted to know if there is a recommended approach.

Thanks

Comment: You can connect a windows slave node into your main server

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Comment: thanks, if you add this as an answer i can mark it as the solution i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a windows slave node into your main server

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

as mentioned earlier in a comment

Answer (score 1):

I have to make Delphi builds on windows with my main jenkins installation is on a CentOS server.

You just need to configure the windows machine as jenkins slave. Java web start is a quick and easy solution (2 minutes) for that:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart
Or step-by-step here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Then on "Project setup" check the "Restrict where this project can be run" and write down the slave name. (There will be time later for more complicated expressions)

Finally istruct your project to exec windows commands adding one of those plugins

- https:// wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin
- https:// wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+Exe+Runner+Plugin

*(sorry for the broken links but it doesn't let me post more than two)*

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few times use netcat.
Otherwise use cygwin and ssh like you said.